# In Laravel migrations what is the parameter in ->nullable($value = true) for?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, database-migration

I came across a migration that uses this syntax: `->nullable('true');` which seems strange, what is that parameter for? I can't find a description for it online. All I know is that it is called `$value`.

Comment: Makes the data in the field _nullable_ - i.e. it can be `NULL` and defaults to `NULL` - the boolean `true` on the method is the optional default, see: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-modifiers - though putting it in quotes (`''`) is somewhat nonsensical as that would make `'false'` truthy...

Comment: @CD001 well the whole purpose of ->nullable is to make it nullable but afaik calling it without the parameter makes it nullable in other words the value can be `NULL`. Tbh, I didn't get your explanation, what defaults to `NULL`, do you mean the default value will be `NULL`?

Comment: I assume you're seeing something like `$table->string('whatever')->nullable('true');` - that basically specifies that the data, in the `whatever` column in the **database table** can be `NULL` - the only oddity is the quote marks around the `true` value (as that would cast it to a string). Normally you just leave it out, like: `$table->string('whatever')->nullable();` since it defaults to `true` anyway - and putting `false` in doesn't make a lot of sense, you'd just leave the `nullable()` method off completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `nullable()` has a default parameter of `true`

```
$table->string('nickname')->nullable();
```

It is the same as

```
$table->string('nickname')->nullable(true);
```

And thus, it is not needed to add the parameter in this case.

---

A common question/confusion is why have this parameter at all? Would we ever `->nullable(false);` since that is the same as just not writing `->nullable()` at all.

Imagine a case where you had a nickname on the user, and you want to change this nickname field from nullable to not nullable. The original migration might have looked like the ones above, and to change it, we could, for explicitness of intent, do the following:

```
$table->string('nickname')->nullable(false)->change();
```